# Purify: Error: Ran out of thread local data space in purify

Tags: hp-ux, rational-purify

I am running purify 7.0 on Hp-UX 11.11B with aCC 3.85.I set the environt variable as below:
export PURIFYOPTIONS="-max_threads=4000 -enable-thread-stack-change=yes"

But still I am getting the below error and the purify comes to an halt with the below error message:

Purify: Error: Ran out of thread local data space.  Exiting.
The maximum number of threads is currently 4000.
To increase the number of allocated threads, use a command like
  (ksh) PURIFYOPTIONS="-max_threads=8000 $PURIFYOPTIONS"; export PURIFYOPTIONS
  (csh) setenv PURIFYOPTIONS "-max_threads=8000 `printenv PURIFYOPTIONS`"

If I put ="-max_threads=8000" it's asking again with to increase the size to 16000 (double whatever is in the PURIFYOPTIONS variable.

Can someone help to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have already heard about this kind of behavior from customer running heavy multithreaded application. The bottom line was that there is not enough space on the machine to run Purify.